# form.attr('action') how to get protocol of a relative url to send correct request

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, ssl

I've a form as following:

```
<form action="/staffpanel/companies/2187/update/" method="post" id="cmpForm">
...
</form>
```

My js code is:

```
    $(document).on('submit', '#cmpForm', function () {
        var form = $('#cmpForm');
        var actionUrl = form.attr('action');

        ajax({
             url: actionUrl,
             type: 'POST',
             processData: false,
             contentType: false,
             success: function (data) {
                ...
             }}});
```

I'm facing this issue, ajax send the request to an url with the wrong protocol. This piece of code works well on local without SSL but not in production over HTTPS.

How can I handle ajax to request over HTTPS instead !

EDIT: Using `.prop` gives the correct URL. I figured out that my issue comes from the endpoint. The view returned by HttpResponseRedirect() to ajax is badly formed, using the bad protocol.

As all my views called in the browser (even with the wrong protocol) are turned correctly to HTTPS, might it be something related to the NGINX conf?

Comment: `cmpSubmit` is not `id` of the form..

Comment: Have you tried with `.prop` like this: `var actionUrl = form.prop('action');`

Comment: which error is reported in console?

Comment: Right with `.prop` I got the correct URL.  I suppose my problem concerns the endpoint as I got this error : `insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint`.